# Going to next route if first fails [Laravel]

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-4, laravel-5.3

I have a route that users can enter their usernames and it will go to their page.

Upon registration I have a validation rule to make sure they can't have a username such as 'login' 'contact' etc.

When a user types in a valid username it is then brought over to a view and displays them correctly, although, now my regular /login /contact views don't work because of the user function

```
Route::get('/', 'Home\PageController@index')->name('home.index');
Route::get('/contact', 'Home\PageController@contact')->name('home.contact');

Route::get('{user}', 'Profile\ProfileController@liveProfileIndex')->name('profile.live.index');
```

Controller

```
public function liveProfileIndex($us){

  $user = User::where('username', $us)->first();

  if ($user) {

    $data = array(
      'user' => $user,
    );

    return view('profile.liveprofileindex', $data);


} else {
    // abort(404);
  }

}
```

Comment: Can you not just maintain a list of excluded usernames?

Comment: well thats typically the same username or url, either way that works. Problem now is if I want to go to /contact, it leads me to the liveProfileIndex instead of /contact, is there anyway to make to go to the next request

Comment: Routes in Laravel are matched in order of definiton. If your `home.index` and `home.contact` routes are defined before the `profile.live.index`, then the first two should match correctly.

Comment: Thanks it worked! Forgot about that

Comment: The only **bulletproof** way to fix this is to prefix the user route with something static: `Route::get('user/{user}')`.

Comment: @JeffreyWesterkamp yeah I know but for simplicity reasons and aesthetic looking websiteurl.com/username